# Python - Function not adding properly

Tags: python, math

While coding I ran into an error and have tried several different fixes that normally work but this one just keeps coming back wrong.

```
if (userchoice == 'D'):
  deposit_amount = input("How much would you like to deposit today?\n ")
  deposit_amount = str(deposit_amount)
  account_balance = str(account_balance)
  balance = deposit_amount+account_balance
  print("Deposit was $" + deposit_amount + ", current balance is $"+ balance)
```

When it prints the balance, it prints the deposit_amount + account_balance together instead of adding them together. IE if you deposit 200 and the account balance is 100 it'll show as 200100, instead of 300.

Comment: That is because your values are strings. In python, adding strings concatenates them. You are going to want to convert the value to a number first. (probably with `int(...)`, if you only want to use whole numbers

Comment: Do any of the solutions posted below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all your `account_balance` variable is not defined in the
   above code snippet and thus should not execute.
2. Secondly you are concatenating strings rather than integers which is
   why you are getting "200100" rather than "300".

**Here is what you want:**

```
if (userchoice == 'D'):
  deposit_amount = int(input("How much would you like to deposit today?\n"))
  deposit_amount = 100
  balance = deposit_amount+account_balance
  print("Deposit was ${}, current balance is ${}".format(deposit_amount, balance))
```

## Sample Output:

> ```
> How much would you like to deposit today?
> 200
> Deposit was $200, current balance is $300
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the values into strings with these lines:

```
  deposit_amount = str(deposit_amount)
  account_balance = str(account_balance)
```

So you are are doing string addition with:

```
balance = deposit_amount+account_balance
```

You want to convert them into integers with:

```
deposit_amount = int(deposit_amount)
account_balance = int(account_balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are converting `deposit_amount` and `account_balance` to `string`. If you have to convert them to `string`. Try doing `balance = int(deposit_amount)+int(account_balance)` instead of `balance = deposit_amount+account_balance`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```py
if (userchoice == 'D'):
  deposit_amount = input("How much would you like to deposit today?\n ")
  deposit_amount = str(deposit_amount)
  account_balance = str(account_balance)
  balance = float(deposit_amount) + decimal(account_balance)
  print("Deposit was $", deposit_amount, ", current balance is $", balance)
```

Also you need to check the user input:

```
try:
    deposit_amount  = float(deposit_amount)
except:
    print("Input is not suitable (must be number) ", deposit_amount)
```